# Display multiple mpld3 exports on a single HTML page

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

I've found the `mpld3` package to be brilliant for exporting a `matplolib` plot to HTML and displaying this via a `flask` app.

Each export comes with a lot of JS which seems unnecessary duplication if you want to display multiple plots within a single page. However I'm not well enough versed in JS to extract the relevant components and then loop through them. The `.fig_to_dict` method gives the necessary JSON to display each chart but then I'm left wondering what JS/ template work is needed to display each chart in turn.

I considered just stacking each plot into a single big figure but I'd like to layout the charts in separate DIVs and so this isn't the right solution.

I think I can see what the JS is doing to display them but I don't have enough knowledge to modify the functions to suit the purpose.

<strike>I haven't included code as I'm expecting this only to be relevant to someone with `mpld3` experience but can supply some sample code if needed.</strike>

Sample HTML output for `mpld3.fig_to_html(fig, template_type="simple")`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mpld3.github.io/js/mpld3.v0.1.js"></script>
<style>
</style>
<div id="fig136845463888164451663379"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var spec136845463888164451663379 = { <snip JSON code> };
  var fig136845463888164451663379 = mpld3.draw_figure("fig136845463888164451663379", spec136845463888164451663379);
</script>
```

I'd thought it would be as simple as linking the two core scripts from the template header and then creating a new script for each JSON export. But that hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're half-way there with your answer. I think what you want to do is something like this, which will embed three figures on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mpld3.github.io/js/mpld3.v0.1.js"></script>
<style>
</style>
<div id="fig01"></div>
<div id="fig02"></div>
<div id="fig03"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var json01 = { <snip JSON code> };
  var json02 = { <snip JSON code> };
  var json03 = { <snip JSON code> };
  mpld3.draw_figure("fig01", json01);
  mpld3.draw_figure("fig02", json02);
  mpld3.draw_figure("fig03", json03);
</script>
```

The json code for each figure can be created in Python by running

```
import json

# ... create matplotlib figure

json01 = json.dumps(mpld3.fig_to_dict(fig))
```

Embed this string at the appropriate place in the HTML document you're creating, and you should be good to go. I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @jakevdp - I'll test this weekend and mark as answered once it's all up and running.

Comment: @PhilSheard I see it was a long weekend:) Especially since your issue was resolved here as well https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3/issues/128

Comment: @Ajasja Haha, yes it was a loooong weekend :) Good spot. Forgot to loop back and mark this as answered. Thanks.

Comment: This answer is correct, but also worth mentioning it was failing for me because my div ids began with a number which isn't allowed in the HTML spec. Prefixing each div with `fig_` sorted the problem for me.

Comment: If I understand correctly this requires you to copy/paste the json text into the HTML doc. How could you automate it, so the figures could be updated daily?

Comment: Found a working solution here: https://gist.github.com/aflaxman/0966ebf06e23e13db1a1

Comment: This is working. However, what should I do if I also want to export the script generated by mpld3 plugin? (interactive plot)

Comment: i just served up each figure using mpld3.fig_to_html() and then in the client it creates a new HTML container (div i think) for each mpld3 html. seems like my approach would result in a larger webpage but less client side processing to convert the json to html in the client right?

Answer (score 3):

Note that since jakevdp's answer was posted mpld3 has had a new release. As of today (September 2014) the mpld3 include has to be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mpld3.github.io/js/mpld3.v0.2.js"></script>
```